# Laravel + AngularJS application structure

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

Currently im in the process of architecturing an application based on Laravel-4 and AngularJS

I do not want to create a single page application.

Is it ok to structure the application along the follwoing lines:

EventsController

- Get() *returns a laravel view*
- index() *returns json array of events*
- show() *returns json event object*
- Store() *saves a json event object*

and generally all the controllers will act in this way, having a get method that serves a laravel blade view and is then manipulated via AngularJS and its partials. Is this best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The plan**

Use laravel to create the routes and let laravel create the views. You only need to create different view templates, which hold references to your angular controllers.

**PagesController**

What you could do is create routes for pages, which renders the views. 
So you could have a PagesController which can do this

**EventsController**

Then use angular to call for the data and have a EventsController for that.
In the EventsController you could add your CRUD, which calls a Event model.

**Then this will be the way the traffic get's called**

The Model needs to return data.
The Controller then will return json, with http status codes.

***Mini example***

Underneath is a way how I do this with flash messages when logging in.

`return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Invalid username or password'), 500);`